# How can i capture the Version history for a particular Data and Highlight the Changes From Current Version to Previous Version

Tags: c#, sql, angularjs

Actually i want to maintain an history for a part number and it's details.
So initially if a add a new part and it's description It's initial version will be 1.0 so on next edit of the part number it will be version 2.0. So here i want to capture the changes done from version 1.0 to 2.0 and highlight the changes done.
So i'm not getting how can i capture the data/changes done.
Can this be done in any simple manner...!!!
Either from any Sql Query or some additional coding needs to be done for this...!!!

Comment: You should research, try to do something then if you have any particular code problem, you can ask. But where is the code? I don't see any.

Comment: Try to explain your question in sections like - Scenario, Problem, Expected Result, Things tried So far, Sample code to give people a better insight into your question.

Comment: Don't forget to reply with a comment about whether it worked for you or not. Mark the Answer as accepted answer if it worked for you. Or reply with the outcome.

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to stack-overflow.

If are looking into maintaining version of the project itself, you can use semantic-release package for automatic version management and document management regarding the same. 
More information here - https://github.com/semantic-release/semantic-release .

Alternatively, if what are looking into maintaining data and version history of data per row, you use **SQL triggers** for this.

On update trigger, insert the change into version_log table.
It could have columns like this.

- Id
- Table_Name - Table in which data was changed
- Column_Changed- The column whose data changed
- Original_Value - Value before update
- New_Value - Value after update
- Original_Version - Version after update
- New_Version - Version after update
- Time_Of_Update

You can then select all changes between two version by creating a report on this table.